# Is this hamiltonian of the form of some well-known physical system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm doing a homework exercise and I'm asked whether some hamiltonian (that is the result of a canonical transformation of some other hamiltonian) is reminiscent of the hamiltonian of some well-known physical system. It's:

$$\tilde{K}=AP^2 + \frac{B}{Q^2}-\frac{C}{Q} $$

where $P$ is the generalized momentum and $Q$ the generalized coordinate.

A few things that immediately come to mind:

1. The $P^2$ term is reminiscent of kinetic energy.
2. Since $\frac{ \partial\tilde{K}}{\partial t}=0$, energy is conserved.
3. The $\frac{1}{Q}$ term could be some Kepler potential.

However the $\frac{1}{Q^2}$ is really throwing me off, any ideas about what that could be, or what the system overall might be?

Comment: It might be nothing more than what it appears: a system that includes an inverse cube force law term. John Baez [describes these in his blog](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/the-inverse-cube-force-law/).

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey But in that case, wouldn't the $\frac{1}{Q}$ be problematic?

Comment: No, there's no reason it would be problematic. Why do you think it would?

Comment: @hft I understood it now, when I commented that I suppose I was assuming that only one force would be in effect, which is obviously not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One likely candidate for what they "want you to say" is a Kepler potential (i.e. produced by an inverse distance-squared force) *viewed in a rotating frame* that scales the rotation rate by a factor $k\geq 0$.

This transformation requires adding an inverse quadratic potential$^1$
$$
\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}(1-k^2)
$$
that is independent of the initial [central potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force), but depends on the reduced mass $\mu$ and angular momentum $L$ of the system, and on the scaling factor $k$ that we choose.

Adding this to our Kepler potential Hamiltonian yields:

$$
H= \frac{1}{2}\mu\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2-\frac{GMm}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}(1-k^2)
$$
where $L$ is the angular momentum, $r$ is the radial distance between masses $m$ and $M$, and $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the system.

This sort of transformation relates to two concepts: the [effective potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential) (which is very important; see the comment by @MichaelSeifert), and [Newton's theorem of revolving orbits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_theorem_of_revolving_orbits).

---

**Effective potential$^2$ ($k=0$)**

For $k=0$, the resulting potential is a classic example of an [effective potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential), where adding an opposing (in our case, centrifugal) potential often enables us to simplify the problem.

In our case, $k=0$ reduces the problem from two to one dimensions (see the red planet's motion in the graphic below for a visualization).

---

**Newton's theorem of revolving orbits ($k \geq 0$)**

Isaac Newton was the first to show that for any particle of mass $m$ and angular momentum $L$ in a central potential, the following are equivalent:

- scaling angular velocity $\dot{\theta}(t) = L/(mr^2(t))$ by $k$ over all time while leaving $r(t)$ unchanged. In this picture, we move to a special rotating frame with a time-varying rotation speed to maintain angular velocity $k\dot{\theta}(t)$.
- scaling the new angular velocity by $k$ at a single moment (by manually changing $L\rightarrow L'=k L$ once) and then evolving under the same central potential plus $(1-k^2)L/(2mr^2)$, which is some "fictitious" inverse distance-cubed force.

This is known as the [Newton's theorem of revolving orbits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_theorem_of_revolving_orbits#Mathematical_statement). (The Hamiltonian it produces was already shown at the top of this answer.)

For $0\leq k<1$, this contributes a centrifugal fictitious force that pushes outward with an inverse cube dependence on radial distance, and the rotation rate is slowed. For $k>1$, it is a centri*petal* force and the rotation rate is increased.

For example, view this Wikimedia image below: the motion of the red and green planet are after this rotating frame transformation.

[image]

For general discussion on inverse cube laws, I recommend  [this excellent blog post by John Baez](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/the-inverse-cube-force-law/).

$^1$ See the [Wikipedia article on Newton's theorem of revolving orbits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_theorem_of_revolving_orbits#Modern_derivation) for context.

$^2$ Thanks again to @MichaelSeifert for pointing out the importance of the effective potential: please read his comment below for context.

Comment: Great explanation! One question though, does Baez explain why the inverse cube appears? He seems to state that the system moves in that way and then moves on.

Comment: Probably better to look at the [derivation of Newton's theorem of revolving orbits on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_theorem_of_revolving_orbits#Modern_derivation). Adding a cubic term slows or speeds rotation by a factor; I'll clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Note that the potential in that Hamiltonian is referred to as the "effective potential" in the case $k = 0$.  This case is quite commonly discussed in intermediate-level physics texts, and is probably (IMO) what the problem author is looking for.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSeifert, this is a good point I did not know about. I'll try to add this to my answer later today.

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelSeifert, I added it to my answer!